# RStudioでのRMeCabの起動時のエラーメッセージ

Tags: r

RStudioでRMeCabを使って文章解析をしようとしています。
library("RMeCab")を読み込んだ後、RStudioのコマンドラインで、”RMeCab”と入力しようとすると、３文字目あたり入力候補一覧が出た瞬間で次のようなWindowsが開きます。

（Window Title）Error Retrieving Help
（Message）R code execution error

R単独でlibraryの読み込みをする際にはこの現象はありませんし、RStudioで他のライブラリを読み込むときにこの症状はありません。すなわちRStudioとRMeCabの組み合わせのときに生じるようです。
気持ちが悪いので何とかしたいのですが、どなたか対処方法を教えていただけませんか。

環境 Windows7 RStudio（いずれも最新）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

私の環境(Windows7 32bit, RStudio0.99.893)でも再現しました。
ヘルプの中に入っている「石田基広『Rによるテキストマイニング入門』森北出版 2008」という文字のところで

```
Error in substring(html, match + 6, match + attr(match, "match.length") -  : 
  invalid multibyte string　・・・・
```

となっていますね。対症療法的ですがRStudioのコード自動補完をやめてTABでの補完に変えること，RMecabの関数についてはTABでの補完も避けることで回避可能です。

Comment: 自動補完機能をオフにしてみたら、唐突にエラーが出る症状はなくなりました。
相変わらずタブで補完表示しようとすると出てきますが、これは自分で対処できます。補完機能使わないほうが、よく覚えますね。
soogieさん、ありがとうございます。